# Microsoft OAuth Access Token Request - 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth

I have been trying to follow Microsoft’s [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), but unfortunately, I have run into an error when trying to request an access token with a client secret. I have ensured that all client IDs, redirect URLs, and scopes match from the retrieval of the authorisation code to the request for the access token, but I have been unable to fix the issues.

This is the initial URL created to retrieve the authorisation code is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
 client_id=237e....&
 redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/xbox-oauth-callback&
 response_type=code&
 response_mode=query&
 code_challenge=aepyAU0M6wE8wRsEDUgp5G0VHpz5-qIAkG5dnuiHWpM&
 code_challenge_method=S256&state=38c597a6-1bdb-49b8-84ff-b5ec770b9930&
 scope=XboxLive.signin&
 prompt=consent
```

Following authentication, I am redirected to `http://localhost:3000/xbox-oauth-callback?code=....047a539&state=38c597a6-1bdb-49b8-84ff-b5ec770b9930` to read the authorisation code from the URL. The error occurs after this when trying to request the access token:

```js
const body = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: 237e....,
    scope: "XboxLive.signin",
    code: "....047a539",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/xbox-oauth-callback",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    code_verifier: "gVCClLeSnLF6zZAGm0LknUze38cHnTA1w27p0EF6vKGy6H3xDdyLHw",
    client_secret: 3ak...,
  });

  const response = await fetch(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body,
    }
  );
```

> Error fetching OAuth tokens: [400] Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried the following JavaScript code to obtain the access token from Azure Active Directory.*

**Code :**

```js
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const authUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
const tokenUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const clientId = '<client_ID>';
const clientSecret = '<client_secret>';
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/xbox-oauth-callback'; 

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const scope = encodeURIComponent(clientId + '/.default');
  const authorizationUrl = `${authUrl}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}`;
  res.send(`Authorization URL: <a href="${authorizationUrl}">${authorizationUrl}</a>`);
});

app.get('/xbox-oauth-callback', async (req, res) => { 
  const { code } = req.query;

  const tokenParams = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri
  };

  try {
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenUrl, querystring.stringify(tokenParams), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    });
    const accessToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;
    res.send(`Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exchanging authorization code for access token:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error exchanging authorization code for access token');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I added the following **URL** to the app as a **Single-page application**,

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

[image]

and the **URL** below in **Web**.

```
http://localhost:3000/xbox-oauth-callback
```

[image]

**Output :**

It ran successfully as shown below:

[image]

I obtained the **Authorization URL** in the browser using the output **URL** above. Next, I clicked on that **Authorization URL** as shown below:

[image]

*It redirected me to the following page, where I received the access token.*

[image]